# Получить путь к веб-приложению (и только) через ServletRequest (или HttpServletRequest)?

Tags: java

Например, у меня есть путь:
`localhost:7777/project/calculator/getUserCalculation?userId=Vasya`,
 а мне нужна только часть :
`localhost:7777/project/calculator/getUserCalculation`

Answer (score 1):

Что бы получить чать URL до `?` используй

[HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29)